# Remove multiple objects with rm()

Tags: r

My memory is getting clogged by a bunch of intermediate files (call them `temp1`, `temp2`, etc.), and I would like to know if it is possible to remove them from memory without doing repeated `rm` calls (i.e. `rm(temp1)`, `rm(temp2)`)?

I tried `rm(list(temp1, temp2, etc.))`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Make the list a character vector (not a vector of names)

```
rm(list = c('temp1','temp2'))
```

or

```
rm(temp1, temp2)
```

Comment: To remove everything in the memory, you can say: rm(list = ls())

Comment: @Sam `rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))` if you want to be sure to get everything.

Comment: Does it work in `%>%`? Such as `list(...) %>% rm(list = .)`

Comment: Would you please explain what it the advantage of `list`? Seems to me unnecessarily complicated to type all the variable names instead of just TAB autocomplete in the second option.

Answer (score 140):

An other solution `rm(list=ls(pattern="temp"))`, remove all objects matching the pattern.

Comment: Described [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711843-Working-Directories-and-Workspaces) by Josh Paulson (I didn't know what `ls(...)` did, but now I guess it's like the Unix bash function ls?) -- whoops, Josh Paulson used a specific variety described by @Sam `To remove everything in the memory, you can say: rm(list = ls())  `

Comment: This works fine but might have a small bug.If there is a object with name 'ABCtemp', it will also be removed. How can I just remove those objects that start with 'temp' and keep the 'ABCtemp'?

Comment: You can simply add more criterion to your pattern. For your example, `pattern="^temp"` will catch only variable beginning by "temp", so not the variable `ABCtemp`.

Comment: Another possibility is the answer given by @BrodieG here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677923/how-to-remove-selected-r-variables-without-having-to-type-their-names

Answer (score 5):

Or using regular expressions

```
"rmlike" <- function(...) {
  names <- sapply(
    match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$..., as.character)
  names = paste(names,collapse="|")
  Vars <- ls(1)
  r <- Vars[grep(paste("^(",names,").*",sep=""),Vars)]
  rm(list=r,pos=1)
}

rmlike(temp)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another variation you can try is (expanding @mnel's answer)
if you have many temp'x'.

Here, "n" could be the number of temp variables present:

```
rm(list = c(paste("temp",c(1:n),sep="")))
```